# Attention something went wrong - default view original state errors magento 2

Tags: magento2

Getting a lot of errors recently and finally found something in the logs but not able to solve it. Already saw other post with clearing the ui_bookmark table and changing FulltextFilter.php file but no result.

[image]

> Terminated request GET
>   x.hypernode.io/index.php?namespace=sales_order_view_rma_list_grid&search=&filters%5Bplaceholder%5D=true&paging%5BpageSize%5D=20&paging%5Bcurrent%5D=1&isAjax=true
>   because client at 213.127.64.175 is already gone

looks like it's only happening in firefox

Comment: check the `var/exception.log`

Comment: nothing in there, only in the sys log